# Change height of div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 divs in a panel. How can i change height of each div? So far i made that it works on one div,but i need it on all 3 of them. This is my code:

```
       function changeheight(_this) {

        var thisText = $(_this).text() ;
        var curHeight = $('.tab-panel div').height();
        $('.tab-panel div').css('height', 'auto');
        var autoHeight = $('.tab-panel div').height();
        $('.tab-panel div').css('height', curHeight + 'px');
        if (thisText == 'Pročitaj više') {

            $('#tab-1,.tab-panel div').animate({
                'height': autoHeight + "px"
            }, 600);
            $(_this).text((thisText  == 'Sakri sadržaj') ? 'Pročitaj više' : 'Sakri sadržaj');
            $(_this).prepend('<img id="theImg" src="Slicice/open.png" />');
        }
        else if (thisText  == 'Sakri sadržaj') {

            $('#tab-1,.tab-panel div').animate({
                'height': '276px'
            }, 600);

            $(_this).text((thisText  == 'Sakri sadržaj') ? 'Pročitaj više' : 'Sakri sadržaj');
            $(_this).prepend('<img id="theImg" src="Slicice/close.png" />');
        }
        return false;
    };
```

and html. Divs with id tad-1 and tab-2 are overflowing,in my case,but i didn't put all the text in this html. I need to get this working for all 3 of them:

```
                <div id="tab-1" class="tab-panel active" >
                    <div >
                        LETO 2015: ALNJA<br><br>
                        Alanja - grad sa mnogo različitih lica. Ovaj grad, smešten u istočnom delu turske obale, 
                        odlikuju veoma izraženi kontrasti. Duge peščane plaže i hladne planinske reke, 
                        drevne ruševine iz rimskog doba i moderni hoteli, Orijent i Evropa na jednom mestu. 
                    <div class="margin-top16px">*Kompletan cenovnik za sve hotele u ponudiagencije pogledajte klikom na:<a href="#">Hellena travel - Alanja leto 2015.</a></div>
                    </div>

                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return changeheight(this);" class="morelink"><img src="Slicice/close.png" id="close">Pročitaj više</a>

                    </div>
                    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-panel" >
                        <div>Alanja - grad sa mnogo različitih lica. Ovaj grad, smešten u istočnom delu turske obale, 
                        </div>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return changeheight(this);" class="morelink"><img src="Slicice/close.png">Pročitaj više</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-panel" >
                        <div>Alanja - grad sa mnogo različitih lica. Ovaj grad, smešten u istočnom delu turske obale, 
                    </div>

                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return changeheight(this);" class="morelink"><img src="Slicice/close.png">Pročitaj više</a>
                    </div>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `onclick="return changeheight(this);"`, In this case you running your function with link in argument.
Try to remove onclick event and use this code:

```
    $('.tab-panel a.morelink').on('click',function () {
        var thisText = $(this).text(),
            curDiv = $(this).closest('.tab-panel').find('div');
            curHeight = curDiv.height();
        curDiv.css('height', 'auto');
        var autoHeight = curDiv.height();
        curDiv.css('height', curHeight + 'px');
        console.log(curHeight, autoHeight)
        if (thisText == 'Pročitaj više') {

            curDiv.parent('.tab-panel').andSelf().animate({
                'height': autoHeight + "px"
            }, 600);
            $(this).text((thisText  == 'Sakri sadržaj') ? 'Pročitaj više' : 'Sakri sadržaj');
            $(this).prepend('<img id="theImg" src="Slicice/open.png" />');
        }
        else if (thisText  == 'Sakri sadržaj') {

            curDiv.parent('.tab-panel').andSelf().animate({
                'height': '276px'
            }, 600);

            $(this).text((thisText  == 'Sakri sadržaj') ? 'Pročitaj više' : 'Sakri sadržaj');
            $(this).prepend('<img id="theImg" src="Slicice/close.png" />');
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: And it was that simple. Thank you so much.